# JPA: join @ElementCollection of type String and do lower or uppercase check

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my Entity i have a @ElementCollection defined:

```
@Entity
public class Test extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> synonyms = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Now im trying to find all records where either the name (to lower case) is like the given string OR its in the list of synonyms.

Everything i was trying so far wasn't working. My function gets the following objects i can work with for building the query:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Test> product, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    ...
}
```

I tried several variants like

```
...
String lowerCaseName "test";

final Predicate namePredicate = builder.or(
    builder.and(builder.lower(product.join(Test_.synonyms)).in(Arrays.asList(lowerCaseName))),
    builder.equal(builder.lower(product.get(Test_.name)), lowerCaseName));
predicates.add(builder.and(namePredicate));
...
```

or doing a join and combine with builder.where but nothing works.
Especially doing a join with the Java String type makes me crazy as i dont know really how to access this value cause it has no mapped name compared to have a typical list of a entity in a "real" 1:n relationship.
I read i could use a builder.isMember function but in this case i dont know how to a lower case like search...

Can anybody help please?

I guess i need a join as i need to do a lower case of each value but im of course not sure...

@Edit
This is more or less the query i would like to produce:

```
select * from test t 
left join test_synonyms on t.id = test_id
where lower(t.name) like '%abc%' or lower(test_synonyms.synonyms) like '%abc%';
```

Comment: You don't test if a collection is IN an element. You test if an element is IN a collection.

Comment: Yeah...one of my tries was "isMember" (i guess you mean that?) but i dont how to do a lower case of the values before in the ElementCollection...

Comment: I'd start by writing the query is SQL, then translating to JPQL (if possible), then stop there, unless there really is a need to translate to a criteria query. My previous comment was just pointing out the obvious: the in clause is backwards.

Comment: Added the query. As im using a Specifications object i would prefer the get it done with the criteriabuilder. Im sure its possible but i just started to work with jpa and therefor i guess im jsut too dumb to get it :)

Comment: With elements you should use isMember api BUT it's eqauls there is no like api  predicate for  elements.

Comment: AFAIK the JPA spec doesn't define joining to a `CollectionTable`, so adding a JOIN would be non-portable, though I know that DataNucleus at least does allow that; check your own provider for whether it allows it. To check it, do the join in JPQL first, something like `SELECT t FROM Test t LEFT JOIN t.synonyms s WHERE LOWER(t.name) LIKE '%abcd% OR LOWER(s) LIKE '%abcd%'`